# Pandas max along n rows

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe with date time index as below

```
137962500   137975000   137987500   138000000   138012500   138025000   138037500   138050000   138062500
Datetime                                    
2020-02-05 11:06:00+00:00   -112.0  -114.0  -114.0  -114.0  -114.0  -116.0  -114.0  -114.0  -114.0
2020-02-05 11:07:00+00:00   -112.0  -111.0  -112.0  -112.0  -112.0  -112.0  -113.0  -113.0  -112.0
2020-02-05 11:08:00+00:00   -113.0  -112.0  -112.0  -112.0  -112.0  -112.0  -112.0  -112.0  -112.0
2020-02-05 11:09:00+00:00   -111.0  -112.0  -111.0  -112.0  -112.0  -112.0  -112.0  -112.0  -112.0
2020-02-05 11:10:00+00:00   -111.0  -112.0  -111.0  -112.0  -113.0  -113.0  -112.0  -112.0  -112.0
```

I am aware of df.max(axis=0) to get the max value along every row. How can we extend this concept to group the dataframe into n columns and get the max within each group?
This is to be able to reduce the number of columns in a 'wide' data format and yet retaining the max values within each small group of columns.

Thanks

Comment: groupby with floor division.

Comment: another method would be to `melt` the dataframe then apply a `groupby` with `max`

Comment: Could you please care to elaborate a bit more @user3483203 ?

Comment: Thanks @Datanovice, I did think of that too. Would that mean using melt first, group every n rows to get a max and then 'unmelt' the result back?

Comment: you could assign it back if you use it transform then by the index, but its hard to say without your expected output and the logic for the grouping

Comment: Ok ,the reason I wanted to go down this route is to speed up the process of visualising the data using a heatmap (Plotly heatmap). Currently heatmap will plot every row and every column of my dataframe and will assign a column scale based on the value.This is slow in large dataframes with 1000's of columns(in my domain of radio signal data). Hence the logic was to 'reduce' the dataframe to a subset dividing it in n small groups and calculating the max, which will ' hopefully' be a representation of the heatmap with lesser memory footprint allowing the browser to plot this without trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Let say you want to assign the columns into groups of 4:

```
group_size = 4
groups = np.arange(df.columns.shape[0]) // group_size
labels = df.columns.to_series().groupby(groups).transform(lambda g: f'{g.min()} - {g.max()}')

df.groupby(labels, axis=1).max()
```

Result:

```
                           137962500 - 138000000  138012500 - 138050000  138062500 - 138062500
Datetime                                                                                      
2020-02-05 11:06:00+00:00                 -112.0                 -114.0                 -114.0
2020-02-05 11:07:00+00:00                 -111.0                 -112.0                 -112.0
2020-02-05 11:08:00+00:00                 -112.0                 -112.0                 -112.0
2020-02-05 11:09:00+00:00                 -111.0                 -112.0                 -112.0
2020-02-05 11:10:00+00:00                 -111.0                 -112.0                 -112.0
```

Comment: Super! Thanks a lot for this @Code Different.
Is there a way to retain the names of the columns in some indirect way - say '137962500 - 138000000' for the first column  and so on, of the resulting dataframe.